# Get Local File name after ZipFile extract()

Tags: python, python-zipfile

How do I get the local file name after ZipFile `extract()` runs?

When I do this:

```
    with zipfile.ZipFile(localZipFilePath, "r") as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            localFilePath = zf.extract(name, '/tmp/')
            print localFilePath
```

The file as it exists in the zip file is: `src/xyz/somefile.txt`

`localFilePath` outputs this: `/tmp/src`

The file that is written here: `/tmp/src/xyz/somefile.txt` and that is what I would like to get in some graceful way.

Comment: No, `localFilePath` is the actual target name that the file is written to, or a directory path if present in the zipfile. There is no need to further process that return value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that is not what I am seeing.  I looked at the source code for ZipFile and can see it never returns the full filepath (full path with filename).  I am asking for a graceful way to get the full path with filename.  Also, in your comment it is not clear what you are saying "No" to.

Comment: I verified the source code as well, and I clearly see that [`targetpath` is what is being created locally, then returned](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/447794596266/Lib/zipfile.py#l1077).

Comment: Ahh, I see now.  The zip file contains empty folders, when I think I am processing a file, I am really processing a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something. The [`ZipFile.extract()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) always returns either the *full* path to either the directory or file it created for that specific zipfile member.

The documentation doesn't state this explicitly, the [source code for the method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/447794596266/Lib/zipfile.py#l1077) is quite clear here:

```
if member.filename[-1] == '/':
    if not os.path.isdir(targetpath):
        os.mkdir(targetpath)
    return targetpath

with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
     file(targetpath, "wb") as target:
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

return targetpath
```

So either the member filename ends in `/` (a directory), in which case the directory is created, or a file is created with the data being copied in. Either way, `targetpath` is the local path of that filesystem entry just created.

I've [opened a Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue23730) to have the documentation updated; as of 2015-03-15 the documentation has been updated to read:

> Returns the normalized path created (a directory or new file).

Comment: I am giving this to Martijin because he identified my misunderstanding of the python code.  Extra at-a-boys if he changes the python documentation ;).

Comment: @MichaelPotter: I have this bookmarked to file an issue, yes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The root problem was that I was not accounting for folders being part of the zip file.  My code was only designed to handle files.

I fixed my code by adding the if statement to detect folders:

```
  with zipfile.ZipFile(localZipFilePath, "r") as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            localFilePath = zf.extract(name, '/tmp/')
            if os.path.isdir(localFilePath):
                continue
            print localFilePath
```